# Place icon next to centered element on hover without centering the icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an icon next to a centered text on hover, wo centering both text and icon. I want the icon to be placed directly after the centered element. Picture should explain it. Preferably I would like to use flexbox. This is what i currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/TmdZ3/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Label</span>
    <i>icon</i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

i {
    display: none;
}

.container:hover > i {
    display: flex;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with your code? Or at least show some of your markup and css.

Comment: @NathanLee The difference is that the text in his "expected" example is still centered while in the "actual" example it moves a bit to the left because of the icon.

Comment: then according to his example, he should just take a new span, make it positioned to be absolute, keeping relative to its immediate parent and then he would get what he is looking for. Just like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974372/place-icon-next-to-centered-element-on-hover-without-centering-the-icon/19974556#19974556) @Simon

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I should have noticed that I want to use http://fontawesome.io/ In other words, use a <i>-element as the icon that shows on hover. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TmdZ3/ Also updated the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make a small change to your markup and put the icon inside the span to then position it relative to its parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/TmdZ3/1/

```
span {
    position: relative;
}

i {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
}
```

Note that the right: -30px; would have to be adjusted according to your icon's size and spacing to the span.

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution. I hoped to be able to find a way without using display:absolute, but I guess it's not possible? Why do you need to do right:-30px instead of left:30px?

Comment: The negative right is used to position the icon outside of the span to the right ;). There's probably actually no solution without position absolute because in such a solution the icon would be displayed inline/inline-block and affect the centering of the span...

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried at present? Have a look at [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4U9ts/) which expands on the code example below.

This should be done by setting the background of the `:hover` css to something like:

```
background-image:url(myicon.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right center;
```

The the regular link css to something like

`padding:0 15px;`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `span`, make its position to be `absolute`, keeping `relative` to its immediate parent and then he would get what he is looking for on hover.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4U9ts/1/)**

**The Code:**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <span>Label</span>
</div>

.wrapper{
    padding:20px;
    border:4px solid grey;
    display:inline-block;
    color:black;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family:verdana;  
    position:relative;
     width:100px;
    height:30px;
}

span{
    padding:0 20px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Hope this helps.